# I have tried but can't create a html code for this table

Tags: css, html

I am unable to create the HTML code for this table. How to do that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFzzZ.png)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Here's the trick: create a table in 2 by 6 in size

Comment: Then merge the data of the 2nd column from 1st to 3rd row, then another merge from 4th to 6th row.

Answer (score 3):

The error you are probably running in to is that "E" needs to be on its own row... There are certainly other ways to do this (including not using tables). But to answer the question you posed:

```html
    <table border=1>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td><td rowspan=2>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>B</td>
      </tr>      
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>E</td>        
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>C</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid ;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
         <td rowspan="2">A</td>                            <td rowspan="3">D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- <td rowspan="2">A</td> -->                   <!-- <td rowspan="3">D</td> -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
         <td rowspan="2">B</td>                       <!-- <td rowspan="3">D</td> -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- <td rowspan="2">B</td> -->                        <td rowspan="3">E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
         <td rowspan="2">C</td>                       <!-- <td rowspan="3">E</td> -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- <td rowspan="2">C</td> -->                   <!-- <td rowspan="3">E</td> -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or with `grid`

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "A D" 
    "A D" 
    "B D" 
    "B E" 
    "C E" 
    "C E"
  ;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.grid .a, 
.grid .b, 
.grid .c, 
.grid .d, 
.grid .e {
  padding: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid .a {
  grid-area: A;
}

.grid .b {
  grid-area: B;
}

.grid .c {
  grid-area: C;
}

.grid .d {
  grid-area: D;
}

.grid .e {
  grid-area: E;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="e">E</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you are using Table for this. Any way we can achieve this by following HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        td {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        table.child tr,
        table.child tr td {
            padding: 0px;
        }

        table.child,
        table.child tr {
            border: 1px solid #fff;
        }

        table.child tr td {
            border: none;
        }

        table.child,
        table.child tr,
        table.child tr td {
            border: none;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table.base,
        table.base tr,
        table.base tr td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table.base tbody tr,
        table.base tbody tr td {
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Table</h2>

    <table border=1 class="base">
        <tr>
            <td>
                A
            </td>
            <td rowspan=3 style="padding: 0">
                <table border=1 class="child">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid">
                            D
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            E
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign=middle>
                B
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                C
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">A</td>                            
    <td rowspan="3">D</td>
  </tr>
   <tr></tr>
  <tr>
     <td rowspan="2">B</td>                       
  </tr>
  <tr>                       
    <td rowspan="3">E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td rowspan="2">C</td>                       
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
table {
  width:55%;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
padding: 45px 10px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
```